# Angular a11y CDK - possible to not import the entire library?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

We import Angular a11y CDK like so:

`import { FocusableOption, FocusKeyManager } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';`

It also imports all of the other a11y features, even those that we don't need yet. Is there a way to import just what we need? Tried importing from `@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/` or something equivalent. Are we going against the grain here by not importing from `public-api`?

[image]

Comment: I had the same question and don't event import anything at all from `@angular/cdk/a11y`. Seems like the other Material components depend/require/use it a lot.